# MySQL Triggers by dividing a number and then floor it

Tags: mysql

Given that I have this database structure.

Table: watchcount

```
uid      steamID         sessionid       watchcount            items
1       234234234        1232432            634                 0
```

I'd like to change column items automatically once watchcount gets updated. After watchcount has been divided by 60, floor the value so that it displays as an integer. Like this:

```
watchcount            items
634                   10
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
create trigger update_items 
before update on watchcount 
for each row 
set new.items = floor(new.watchcount/60);
```

[doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Comment: However mysql wont let me update the table after this. UPDATE  `database1`.`watchcount` SET  `watchcount` =  '123' WHERE  `watchcount`.`uid` =21

MySQL said: Documentation

#1442 - Can't update table 'watchcount' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Comment: @user3787029, thanks for catching that. It didn't work because we were trying to update the same table. There is a simpler syntax in this case. See updated answer.